# Obtain SHA256 Value for Subject Key Identifier

Tags: hashing

Using Keytool we can view the details of a Keystore with the command

```
keytool -list -v -keystore <KeystoreName>
```

This returns a set of values including a Subject Key Identifer

```
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 60 7B 66 1A 45 0D 97 4B  CA 89 50 2F 7D 04 CD 34
0010: A8 FF FC FD
]
]
```

This is the SHA1 Key Identifier. How do I obtain the SHA 256 Key Identifier for the same keystore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Subject Key Identifier* (SKI or SKID) is a property (an X.509 extension) of an individual certificate.

It is typically computed as a SHA-1 hash when a certificate is being signed, the data that is hashed may vary but will typically include at least the *subjectPublicKey* bit string, and it may not be a complete 160 bit SHA-1 value.

The only things that (technically) care about how the hash is created are the system doing the signing, or sometimes the system doing creating the request, since it can be added to a request. Outside of that, it is treated as an opaque fingerprint or unique ID - its value need only be compared to identify a specific certificate or its issuer (to assist and optimise [path checking](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37409/certificate-chain-checking)), it need not be recomputed.

If you want to properly compute the SHA-256 hash, then you will need to find out what fields exactly your system uses to compute the hash, and use that as input to SHA-256. See [RFC 5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280), especially [§4.2.1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.1) and [§4.2.1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.2). The signed data is *probably* just the *subjectPublicKey* or *subjectPublicKeyInfo* in binary DER format, the latter seems to be the case for an OpenSSL signed certificate.

This (expired) RFC draft proposes usage of SHA-2 hashes for subject key identifiers:
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-turner-additional-methods-4kis-08

There's a feature request and patch for this languishing slightly in [OpenSSL bug #2599](http://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=2599)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't exist, and you really don't need it to exist.  A certificate needs only a *unique* identifier in the Subject Key IDentifier property that can tell your system which key to use to decrypt it.  It doesn't even need to be a hash, it just needs to be unique.  You could just as well use the text "Zeutheus Key #1" for a SKID, as long as you don't re-use it to label a different key.

If you really want to use SHA-256 to generate your a SKID, go ahead.  Once you have it, you'll have to create a new certificate request that uses the new value, and have it signed.  Some tools, like Microsoft's certutil.exe, allow you to set the specific value for any OID on a certificate request.  You could generate the SHA-256 hash of your public key, then place that value in the SKID OID.  But that's a whole lot of work you don't have to do when the default is to generate a SHA-1 hash that works well enough for the purpose.